# Grpc not increasing max size of the message: received message larger than max

Tags: python, grpc, grpc-python

I am using grpc to send some pretty large messages (the parameters of a machine learning model over the network). The problem is that I am getting the following error when I make a grpc call:

```
grpc: received message larger than max (261268499 vs. 4194304)
```

As suggested in other posts I tried to increase the max message size on the channel and the grpc server, but I keep getting the same error. Any idea on how to get this to work?

My code for the server:

```
maxMsgLength = 1024 * 1024 * 1024
server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10),
                     options=[('grpc.max_message_length', maxMsgLength),
                              ('grpc.max_send_message_length', maxMsgLength),
                              ('grpc.max_receive_message_length', maxMsgLength)])
```

The client:

```
maxMsgLength = 1024 * 1024 * 1024
channel = grpc.insecure_channel(ip_port, 
                                options=[('grpc.max_message_length', maxMsgLength),
                                         ('grpc.max_send_message_length', maxMsgLength),
                                         ('grpc.max_receive_message_length', maxMsgLength)])
```

Edit:

Not a solution, but maybe gives a little bit more insight into the problem. For some reason, if I set the max message size to  1024 * 1024 * 1024 it ends up defaulting to 4194304 as the error message implies. Not really sure why that happens. But anyways, I tried reducing the max message size to 1024 * 1024 * 200 and it shows the correct max message size in the error message (209715200). It seems like there is a problem where grpc is not setting the max message size properly. Not sure how to get around this though.

The maximum number I can use where the error message shows the proper max value is 2^28. If I put a max message size of 2^29 it defaults to 4194304.

Answer (score 0):

You can send your data in chunk using grpc streaming API as mentioned in the below example. Although, more details are needed for better clarity of your exact requirement.

##### Protobuf File

```protobuf
syntax = "proto3";

package pb.foo_service;

service FooService {
    rpc TestRpc(TestRequest) returns (stream TestResponse) {}
}

message TestRequest {}

message TestResponse {
  bytes data = 1;
}
```

##### Servicer

```py
class FooService(pb_grpc.FooServiceServicer):

    def TestRpc(
        self,
        request: pb.TestRequest,
        context: grpc.ServicerContext
    ) -> Iterator[pb.TestResponse]:
        with open("test_file", 'rb') as content_file:
            content = content_file.read()
    yield my_generated_module_pb2.Response(data=content)
```

Comment: But the question is different. Often you are not the one who implements the server :(